# Disk I/O bench marking

Tags: linux, asterisk, freepbx

I have a large call canter with 250~ concurrent calls. The Queue application flat file for Queue Logs. The system uses Asterisk and Queuemetrics. Both services run on the same server. Specs are 16Cores and 64 GB RAM. 
The whole system stuck after 3-4 days, I'm quite sure it due to too much I/O operations. 
Is there disk I/O plotting tools?

Comment: Why would you think so? Did you monitor anything? If its a long running process its kindof hard to think its the IO. Checked the memory consumtion?  btw. canter = center?

Comment: The load average is all time high. It ranges from 2.5 to 12. I think increase in load average is due to I/O blocking. One Asterisk process writes too much call queue logs in the disk and the other process, which is queuemetrics application, reads that file and writes the logs in the mysql db.

Comment: load average <16 on 16 core system mean you always have cpu which do NOTHING.

Answer (score 0):

Let say you have 1000 calls(unlikly) with average call duration(ACD) of 15 sec(also unlikly).

So. You have 1000/15=66.66 calls ending each second in WORST case.

Now let say each call call 10 agents.

You get 2+10+1 lines of text to be put into queue_log per each call.

Let say each line is 1kb(usually it is 250 bytes or less).

So you get 13kb*66.66=865kb each second writed to disk.

Are you really think your disk so slow?

Comment: So, this issue was not related to core I/O bottleneck. Elastix/FreePBX CDR table use 'datetime' field to lookup cdrs. A simple query with 150Millions records lookup the entire table. So I optimized the db schema by indexing the cdr table, other tables, and reduced the log writing. Now there are no warning related to high resource utilization in NewRelic portal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ramdisk for;

recordings(record_cache_dir=/dev/shm in asterisk.conf)

logs to /dev/shm (with logrotate)

mysql(memory table)